# Trying to add more space between labels in x-axis on pyplot histogram

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to make a histogram from dictionary that looks something like

```
words = {'STORES': 8, 'ELECTRIC': 15, 'CAPITAL': 7, 'FLORIDA': 6, '-CL': 35, 'NATURAL': 6, 'ELECTRONICS': 8, 'INDUSTRIES': 35, 'GROUP': 42, 'POWER': 11, '&': 38, 'HOLDINGS': 14, 'GAS': 10, 'GENERAL': 15, 'PRODUCTS': 8, 'AMERICA': 8, 'NATIONAL': 7, 'A': 31, 'B': 7, 'CENTRAL': 7, 'INTL': 14, 'ENERGY': 21, 'CORP': 288, 'SYSTEMS': 18, 'REALTY': 8, 'TECHNOLOGIES': 13, 'TECHNOLOGY': 6, 'PROPERTIES': 6, 'RESOURCES': 16, 'FIRST': 9, 'STACKOVERFLOW': 10, 'INDS': 8, 'VERIZON': 13, 'OF': 10, 'COMMUNICATIONS': 9, 'AMERICAN': 34, 'HELLO': 6}
```

with x-axis representing words.key() and y-axis representing words.values(). I have tried several method to make a nice looking histogram. Below is one of my tries...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import numpy as np

ax = pl.subplot(111)
width=1.0
ax.bar(range(0,len(words)), words.values(), width=width/2)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,len(words)) + width/2)
ax.set_xticklabels(words.keys())
pl.show()
```

The problem of this code is that the labels on the x-axis are overlapping each other which makes the histogram incomprehensible. Could anyone give me a solution to this situation? I really want to have some control over how far the labels are separated to each other. Also, it will be nice to have all bars lined up at the center instead of lined up from left.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- change the size of the figure. Most of all pay attention to the ratio: if you have too many columns in a bar chart, it should have a wider ratio.
- change the orientation of the text. Rotating by 90 degrees makes it much more legible.

I tried the following code, and it worked great:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import numpy as np

fig = pl.figure(figsize=(18,4)) #sets a different size (inches wide, inches tall)
ax = pl.subplot(111)
width=1.0
ax.bar(range(0,len(words)), words.values(), width=width/2)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,len(words)) + width/2)
ax.set_xticklabels(words.keys())

locs, labels = pl.xticks() #gets labels
pl.setp(labels, rotation=90) #sets rotation of the labels

pl.show()
```

You could also change the font, but I don't think that's needed here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried rotation, and no more overlapping is happening, but the bottom part of the words are cut off when looking at the picture of it.. Could it be solved somehow? Also is it possible to remove empty white space after the last bar?

Comment: Strange... On a iPython Notebook the bottom isn't cut off, that's why I didn't notice it. `pl.tight_layout()` seems to fix that though.

Comment: That worked out for me. Thanks for the answers so far! But will it be possible to manually set the width of columns? Seems to me that we are going around the direct solution...